# Do you put the beginTransaction(); before or within the `try` block

Tags: php, transactions

Should I do

```
$dbh->beginTransaction();
try{
```

Or

```
try{
  $dbh->beginTransaction();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't really matter, it will run the code indifferent of it's position.
But you want to put the `rollback()` in the `catch`, and with that setup it's not readable if you put `begin` outside.

I would vote for inside the `try`.

Answer (score 4):

It probably doesn't really matter. However, it's better to place the `beginTransaction` **outside** the `try`. When the `beginTransaction` fails, it should not execute the `rollback`.

Answer (score 1):

add it inside the `try`/`catch` block, so you can catch any `PDOException`:

```
try {
    $dbh->beginTransaction();    // start transaction
    $stmt = $dbh->query($query); // run your query
    $dbh->commit();              // commit
} catch(PDOException $ex) {      // if exception, catch it
    $dbh->rollBack();            // rollback query
    echo $ex->getMessage();      // echo exception message
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case it doesn't matter, as beginTransaction will return false on failure. If it threw exceptions, you would want it inside of a nested try block (otherwise you'd execute rollBack() after catching the exception which would fail because no transaction was started).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to catch the possible errors that the beginTranscation method should throw, go for the second one.